# How to dynamically give classnames in React Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, node.js, tailwind-css, tsx, tailwind-ui

I have this code where i generate a table from json data. I pass along a config file that is used in deciding which columns are most important and which are not important and will be hidden in smaller screens using method "decidePrioColumns". The issue is the first column of the table may vary because of this. How can i apply "firstColumnStyle" to the first column of the table if it changes based on the screen size?

tsx file:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MoreBtn from "./MoreBtn";
import { PriorityColumnNames } from "@/lib/config/priocolumnnames.config";

function classNames(...classes: any) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function CollapsingTable(props: { objects: string[] }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [applyFirstColumnStyle, setApplyFirstColumnStyle] = useState(true);

  const baseColumnStyle: string =
    "text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900";
  const firstColumnStyle: string = "py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 sm:pl-0";
  const nextColumnStyle: string = "px-3 py-3.5";
  const midPrioColumnStyle: string = "hidden sm:table-cell";
  const lowPrioColumnStyle: string = "hidden lg:table-cell";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.objects.length > 0) {
      setData(props.objects);
      console.log(props.objects);
      setColumns(Object.keys(props.objects[0]));

      window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
      };
    }
  }, [props.objects]);

  function handleWindowResize() {
    const shouldApply = window.innerWidth > 1025; 
    setApplyFirstColumnStyle(shouldApply);
  }

  function decidePrioColumns(data: string): string {
    const matchingColumn = PriorityColumnNames.columnnames.find(
      (column) => column.name === data
    );

    if (matchingColumn) {
      if (matchingColumn.prio == 0) {
        console.log("name");

        return baseColumnStyle;
      }
      return midPrioColumnStyle + " " + baseColumnStyle;
    } else {
      return lowPrioColumnStyle + " " + baseColumnStyle;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="sm:flex sm:items-center">
        <div className="sm:flex-auto">
          <h1 className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
            Users
          </h1>
          <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-700">
            A list of all the users in your account including their name, title,
            email and role.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-4 sm:ml-16 sm:mt-0 sm:flex-none">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="block rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-center text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
          >
            Add user
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="-mx-4 mt-8 sm:-mx-0">
        <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {columns.map((column, index) => (
                <th
                  key={index}
                  scope="col"
                  className={classNames(
                    decidePrioColumns(column),
                    applyFirstColumnStyle && index === 0
                      ? firstColumnStyle
                      : nextColumnStyle
                  )}
                >
                  {column}
                </th>
              ))}
              <th
                key="edit"
                scope="col"
                className="relative py-3.5 pl-3 pr-4 sm:pr-0"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Edit</span>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
            {data.map((person, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                {columns.map((column, index) => (
                  <td className="w-full max-w-0 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:w-auto sm:max-w-none sm:pl-0">
                    {person[column].toString()}
                    <dl className="font-normal lg:hidden">
                      <dt className="sr-only">Title</dt>
                      <dd className="mt-1 truncate text-gray-700">
                        {person.title}
                      </dd>
                      <dt className="sr-only sm:hidden">Email</dt>
                      <dd className="mt-1 truncate text-gray-500 sm:hidden">
                        {person.email}
                      </dd>
                    </dl>
                  </td>
                ))}
                {/* <td className="hidden px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 lg:table-cell">
                  {person.title}
                </td>
                <td className="hidden px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 sm:table-cell">
                  {person.email}
                </td>
                <td className="px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                  {person.role}
                </td> */}
                <td
                  key="more"
                  className="py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-0"
                >
                  <MoreBtn />
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

config file:

```
  columnnames: [
    { name: "name", prio: 0 },
    { name: "email", prio: 0 },
    { name: "username", prio: 1 },
    { name: "phone", prio: 1 },
    { name: "website", prio: 1 },
  ],
};
```